# Mint, unable to install new version of NodeJS and NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I am unable to install a newer version of NodeJS than 8.10.0 on my Linux Mint machine. I've added repositories of newer versions (10.x and 11.x) via bash but neither works, apt does not find any updates for NodeJS nor NPM package. I've also tried cleaning apt cache, but that didn't work either.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What exactly did you do?

Comment: Followed their official instructions.. curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -, then apt update && apt install nodejs, then tried cleaning apt cache with apt clean, removing added repositories and adding them again.. nothing works

Comment: That script says it supports Debian and Ubuntu, not Mint.

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu and I this worked for me before on other Mint machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I have the latest Tina distribution of mint, which is not added yet in the script as the supported distro. Downloading the script with `wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x` and adding `check_alt "Linux Mint"    "tina"     "Ubuntu" "bionic"` next to other predefined distros and then running it again solved the issue for me.

Source:
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/878